# How to display only value on Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Please help me. how to display only value on Laravel.

when i'm var_dump($data->count_date)
i got like this.

```
int(347)
```

how to remove int()?

Thks

Comment: `echo $data->count_date;`

Comment: No need to remove it. Just use $data->count_date whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

php [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump) — Dumps information about a variable, not the variable alone.

`$data->count_date` is an integer number value, you can use it like any other integer, for example:

```
$value=$data->count_date+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do, It will only return the value.

```
dd($data->count_date);
```